# Project Euler #68 wrong answer for simple algorithm

Tags: clojure

So I'm attempting [problem 68](https://projecteuler.net/problem=68) in Project Euler. I came up with a simple algorithm. However, my submission comes up wrong. Do note that the algorithm works correctly for the 3-case. Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong. I've been stuck with this for some time now.

```
; https://projecteuler.net/problem=68

(ns eul
  (:require [clojure.math.combinatorics :as combo]))

; Try the 3-case first to see if correct.

;     a
;      \
;       b
;      / \
;     e - c - d
;    /
;   f

(->> (combo/permutations (range 1 7))
     (filter (fn [[a b c d e f]] (and (= (+ a b c) (+ d c e) (+ f e b))
                                      (< a d)
                                      (< a f))))
     (map (fn [[a b c d e f]] (->> [a b c d c e f e b]
                                   (map str)
                                   (apply str))))
     (map #(Integer/parseInt %))
     (sort >)
     (first))

    ;     a
    ;     |
    ;     b -- e - d
    ;     |     \
    ;     |      g
    ;     |     / \
    ; j - c -- i   f
    ;         /
    ;        h

(->> (combo/permutations (range 1 11))
     (filter (fn [[a b c d e f g h i j]] (and (= (+ a b c) (+ d e b) (+ f g e) (+ h i g) (+ j c i))
                                              (< a d) (< a f) (< a h) (< a j))))
     (map (fn [[a b c d e f g h i j]] (->> [a b c d e b f g e h i g j c i]
                                           (map str)
                                           (apply str))))
     (filter #(= (.length %) 16))
     (map biginteger)
     (sort >)
     (first))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the arrangement of the vars were wrong in the second case. The problem statement did not match.